# CakePHP validateUnique not found

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.7

Created a UsersTable.php file by baking from my database.

I have the user name working as an email address just fine.

But then I wanted to ensure that new users weren't trying to create an account with an existing email address. I found this pretty simple [validator method](https://api.cakephp.org/3.7/class-Cake.ORM.Table.html#_validateUnique) in the docs, which looks to be exactly what I need.

```
    $validator
        ->email('email')
        ->requirePresence('email', 'create')
        ->allowEmptyString('email', false)
        ->validateUnique('email', true);
```

However... I get:

```
Call to undefined method Cake\Validation\Validator::validateUnique()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

validateUnique is a method on the Table object, not the Validator object. You need to use the Validator::add method as shown in the examples on the page to which you linked.